# An item with the same key has already been added: Key: Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.ProjectContextBuilder+LibraryKey

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have changed my project to use net451 instead of dnx451, since dnx is going out.

To publish the project now, you have to use the command

`dotnet publish`

When i run this command i get an error saying

> An item with the same key has already been added: Key:
>   Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.ProjectContextBuilder+LibraryKey

Does anyone know how to sort this?

Comment: `dnx451` is still the way to go for applications. `net451`is **ONLY for Class Libraries**!!! Are you using dotnet-cli tooling rather than dnx?

Comment: dotnet-cli tooling?  I am using the dotnet command line tool. net451 is just for class libraries?  What do you use for websites then?

Comment: Last time I tried out dotnet-cli, `dnxcore50` moniker still worked. Was 1 month ago though. Just can't remember if full .net framework was supported that time

Comment: dotnet-cli is just changing the tooling used to build, publish and compile the applications as well as provide the runtime packages via nuget rather than having an runtime installed (`dnvm upgrade` previously did download this runtime assemblies like `System.Runtime`, with dotnet-cli you get it via nuget). The way applications are made is unaffected, with exception if you want to run asp.net core rc2 web applications in dnx you need an additional package (right now its side-by-side, but dnx doesn't receive any updates and with rc2 release dotnet-cli is the official tooling